# How to get String from Array in Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I try to get a String from an Array, which I get over iterate an array.

```
let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

        for item in parsed as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
            doSomething(item["title"])
        }
```

xCode is printing the following error while get "title" from "item":

```
Cannot subscript a value of Type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' with an index of type 'String'
```

Whats my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this might help you. Try it out, and let me know if it works.

```
if let parsed = (try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:  NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? [[String : AnyObject]]) {
for items in parsed {
    if let item = items as? [String : AnyObject] {
        let title = item["title"]
        print("@@@ item :: \(title)")
    }
}}
```

Comment: signal abort in line with "print"

Comment: let title = item["title"] as? String
print("@@@ item :: \(title)")

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    if let parsed = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject] {

        for (key, value) in parsed {
            print(key)
            print(value)
            // do something

        }
    }
```

i just tried this simple code - this works on swift 2.0

```
let jsonData = "{\"hello\":\"world\"}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

if let parsed = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject] {

    for (key, value) in parsed {
        print(key)
        print(value)
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x19ebcb150) to 'NSDictionary' (0x19ebcb380).
(lldb)" in the "if-line"

Comment: are you using swift 2.0?

Comment: I think and hope. Where can I check it?

Comment: Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81)